# MySQL decimal(10,2) Increase By 10%

Tags: mysql

I have a column with data type decimal(10,2).

I want to increase all of the current values by 10%.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
 UPDATE `Table1` SET `Value` = `Value` * 1.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? For negative values, this makes data 10% smaller (further away from zero).

```
update table set data = data * 1.1;
```